# Continue uploadify uploads while the button is hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I'm building a page where a user can upload multiple files through uploadify. I'm trying to do it so when the user has selected which files to upload, he can click a button to hide the upload queue and go about doing other things, and later he can click a button to bring up the uploads panel again and see the progress.

However it seems that if the upload button is hidden, then uploadify cancels any ongoing uploads.

What can be done about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the height of the container div to 0 rather than hiding it. It works.